# Ошибка "переполнение" при SQL-запросе

Tags: access, delphi, sql

Доброго времени суток.

Возникает ошибка с выводом сообщения "Переполнения", когда делаю запрос на добавление в базу строки. В таблице 27 столбцов, может быть ошибка из-за их большого количества. В чем проблема?

Comment: Количество столбцов ни при чём. В какой-то столбец не влезает вводимое значение. Надо смотреть описание таблицы и команду insert (со значениями)

Comment: я проверял по размерам всё нормально там значения не большие то по сути. строка максимум ~150 символов, числа максимум 15 цифр
P.S. ошибка возникает кстати уже на AdoQuery1.ExecSql;

Comment: А когда возникает ошибка? На любой insert или нет?

Comment: нет именно с этой базой и этим запросом, так то остальное работает нормально.

Comment: Проверьте типы вводимых значений.
Возможна ошибка при неявном преобразовании типа.

Comment: Я проверял. Если бы было несоответствие типов, он бы выдал другую ошибку, даже еще при присвоении. Если что, то я делаю через параметры - то есть

    Adoquery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Фамилия').Value:=<Фамилия>

Comment: Кто сделает следующий ход в игре "Угадай мою ошибку"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, проблема с моей стороны всё-таки. В общем, на числовое значение выпадало иногда `null` или  '',  поэтому ошибка была. Дико извиняюсь спасибо за помощь. Просто добавление шло в цикле от 0 до 357. Ошибку нашел на 151 шаге только.